# Java.Lang.IllegalStateException while using FormsAppCompatActivity in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

The Xamarin android code is giving runtime exception when used with following code:

```
public class MyActivity: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.toolbar;
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.tabs;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());            
    }
}
```

When running the app, its builds successfully. But in Runtime iot gets into following error StackTrace:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.IllegalStateException' was thrown.
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <IL 0x00011, 0x00078>
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallIntMethod (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00069, 0x00297>
at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransactionInvoker.Commit () <IL 0x00038, 0x00143>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.SwitchContentAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool,bool,bool) <IL 0x00140, 0x00953>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnPushAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) <IL 0x00005, 0x00063>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.PushViewAsync (Xamarin.Forms.Page,bool) <IL 0x00003, 0x00053>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.<OnElementChanged>b__13_0 (Xamarin.Forms.Page) <IL 0x00003, 0x0004f>
at Xamarin.Forms.EnumerableExtensions.ForEach<Xamarin.Forms.Page> (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<Xamarin.Forms.Page>,System.Action`1<Xamarin.Forms.Page>) <0x00157>
An unhandled exception occured.

at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.OnElementChanged (Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs`1<Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage>) <IL 0x001bb, 0x00e0f>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1<Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage>.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage) <0x00827>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.VisualElementRenderer`1<Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage>.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) <0x0012b>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Platform.CreateRenderer (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) <IL 0x00021, 0x0014f>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.MasterDetailContainer.set_ChildView (Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement) <IL 0x00049, 0x001df>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailPageRenderer.UpdateDetail () <IL 0x0001d, 0x000e3>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.MasterDetailPageRenderer.HandlePropertyChanged (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x0002c, 0x00157>
at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>.invoke_void_object_PropertyChangedEventArgs (object,System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) <IL 0x0002f, 0x0008b>
at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (string) <IL 0x00012, 0x000d7>
at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (string) <IL 0x00002, 0x0005f>
at Xamarin.Forms.MasterDetailPage.set_Detail (Xamarin.Forms.Page) <IL 0x0007b, 0x002eb>
at eWorker.App.SetRootPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page) [0x00025] in C:\SIProducts\360\Dev\Frontend\BugFixes\Source\BIF\Source\eWorker\XamarinApp\Shared\eWorkerShared\App.cs:97
at eWorker.Views.HomePage.OnAppearing () [0x0000e] in C:\SIProducts\360\Dev\Frontend\BugFixes\Source\BIF\Source\eWorker\XamarinApp\Shared\eWorkerShared\Views\HomePage.cs:39
at Xamarin.Forms.Page.SendAppearing () <IL 0x00025, 0x0011f>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.FragmentContainer.set_UserVisibleHint (bool) <IL 0x0004b, 0x002a3>
at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer/<>c__DisplayClass52_0.<SwitchContentAsync>b__1 () <IL 0x00014, 0x0008f>
at Xamarin.Forms.Forms/AndroidPlatformServices/<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<StartTimer>b__1 () <IL 0x00006, 0x00053>
at Java.Lang.Thread/RunnableImplementor.Run () <IL 0x00011, 0x00097>
at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0000a, 0x000a3>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.ba4e6bb4-0814-4b71-9867-78bee59c6f1f (intptr,intptr) <IL 0x00011, 0x0003b>
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1448)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1466)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.n_run(Native Method)
    at mono.java.lang.RunnableImplementor.run(RunnableImplementor.java:29)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03): Shutting down VM
hreadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41b6bc08)
```

This error occurs at points where `Navigation.PushAsync` or `Navigation.PushModalAsync` is called.

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D I found that the issue is while it saves the previous stage of App. It worked when the old app is manually removed and then the App is installed while debugging.

But this can not be a proper solution, so any suggestions/help is welcomed.

Comment: Did you find a proper code fix though? It would not be a good idea to manually removed and reinstall the app

Comment: I didn't find any proper fix. I tried few like overriding onSaveInstanceState method, but didn't work. If you can help in this?